# Owin Hosting - CallCancelled CancellationToken

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm trying to understand how to use the IOwinRequest.CallCancelled CancellationToken IOwinRequest.  I assumed that the token would get flagged any time the request became invalid (for the following cases):

- Disposing the object returned by WebApp.Start.
- The HttpClient.GetAsync Task is cancelled or disposed.

In all these cases, it seems that the CallCancelled request is never flagged.  Why?

EDIT: I found an error in my code and my first point "Disposing the object returned by WebApp.Start" works now. Disposed/Cancelled client requests still don't trigger the server request token to flag though.

For some background, I am trying to implement long-polling, where the server suspended the request thread until some data arrived to return to the client, or if the request is cancelled.  To implement this, my suspending loop will fall out if the cancellation token is flagged.  If it's not flagged, the request thread will NEVER end unless there is something to return.  Since the token is never flagged, my server could end up with an infinite number of requests that never end.